# Can I created date property if user not send?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I created the rule by using the Firebase Bolt compiler.

```
// ####### Root

path / {
  read() = true;
  write() = false;
}

// ######## USERS PHOTOS
// Allow anyone to read the list of Photos.
path /users_photos {
  read() = true;
}

// All individual Photos are writable by anyone.
path /users_photos/$id is Photos {
  write() = isSignedIn();
}

type Photos {
  image: String,
  user_id: String,
  removed: Boolean,
  dt_created: InitialTimestamp,
  dt_updated: CurrentTimestamp
}


type CurrentTimestamp extends Number {
    validate() = this == now;
}

type InitialTimestamp extends Number {
  validate() = initial(this, now);
}


//
// Helper Functions
//
isSignedIn() = auth != null;
// Returns true if the value is intialized to init, or retains it's prior
// value, otherwise.
initial(value, init) = value == (prior(value) == null ? init : prior(value));
```

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md

My script:

```
/*Upload*/
VigiApp.controller('UploadController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', 'FirebaseURL', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, FirebaseURL) {
    // upload on file select or drop
    $scope.upload = function (file, id) {
        $('.page-spinner-bar').removeClass('ng-hide hide').addClass('ng-show show');

        id = typeof id !== 'undefined' ? id : null;
        Upload.base64DataUrl(file).then(function(base64){
            //auth
            var fbAuth = FirebaseURL.getAuth();
            //Ref
            var usersPhotosRef = FirebaseURL.child("users_photos");
            usersPhotosRef.push({'image': base64,'removed': true, 'user_id': fbAuth.uid}, function(error){
                if (error) {
                    alert('Error: Something went wrong when creating your post please try again');
                } else {
                  var newID = usersPhotosRef.key();
                  if(id !== null){
                      $('#'+id).css("background-image", "url('"+base64+"')");
                      $('#'+id).css("background-size", "100% 100%");
                  }
                }   

                $('.page-spinner-bar').removeClass('ng-show show').addClass('ng-hide hide');
            });
        });
    }     
}]);
```

Compile ...

```
>firebase-bolt mmgv-vigiapp.bolt -o rules.json
bolt: Generating rules.json...
```

And deploy ...

```
>firebase deploy:rules

=== Deploying to 'vivid-heat-2144'...

i  deploying rules

+  Deploy complete!

Dashboard: https://vivid-heat-2144.firebaseio.com
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users_photos/-K5VL1m04oF8s2xp8oTf failed: permission_denied
```

The rules created:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    "users_photos": {
      ".read": "true",
      "$id": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['image', 'user_id', 'removed', 'dt_created', 'dt_updated'])",
        "image": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "user_id": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "removed": {
          ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
        },
        "dt_created": {
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == (data.val() == null ? now : data.val())"
        },
        "dt_updated": {
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() == now"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I remove the date, it works.

```
...
type Photos {
  image: String,
  user_id: String,
  removed: Boolean,
}
...
```

How can I generate the creation date and update?
Where is my wrong, please?

Comment: Are you using the firebase generated timestamp (Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) for the creation and update dates?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying =)  it's possible?

Comment: Personally i use <= instead of == for comparing timestamps. But can you check if it works when you only use creation date or update? Maybe it is just one of the 2 that gives trouble.

Comment: @AndréKool Until recently I did the same. But it turns out that when you use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, the value of `now` in the security rules is guaranteed to be the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding a Photo, you pass this information:

```
usersPhotosRef.push({'image': base64,'removed': true, 'user_id': fbAuth.uid}
```

Your security rules, require these properties:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['image', 'user_id', 'removed', 'dt_created', 'dt_updated'])",
```

There is no magic "default value" for `dt_created` and `dt_updated`, so you'll need to pass these in from your application code:

```
usersPhotosRef.push({
  'image': base64,
  'removed': true, 
  'user_id': fbAuth.uid,
  'dt_created': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  'dt_updated': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```

Since this snippet is adding a new record, `dt_created` and `dt_updated` are set to the same value. When you update a record, you'll only want to set `dt_updated`.